# HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups Result

Tags: .net, active-directory

I have configured my web application to run under windows authentication mode, I also used HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups to retrieve a list of groups the logon user belongs to.

When I compare my result with another tool from http://userviewer.sourceforge.net/ I actually see some differences (though most of them match).

This leads me to think that are there any diferent type of AD groups in the directory that .Net API will pick on?

The major difference I noticed is that HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups does not return Distribution Group in general, but in some rare cases I also saw one distribution group returned.

Thanks

Hardy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardy-

Not getting distribution groups back is expected. That property is returning the user's security token. Distribution groups aren't included in the security token when it's generated.